# Permission issue on Alpine Linux when Spring Boot app with Logback trying to write logs to /var/log/

Tags: spring-boot, docker, permissions, logback, alpine-linux

I have a Spring Boot Java app and I'm using the logback logging framework. I've set this up with spring profiles, so that when I run a containerized instance of the app with a specific profile (by specifying the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment var), logback will include a rolling file appender that write logs to `/var/log/log.txt`.

The base docker image I'm using is `amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk` (which is Alpine under the hood) and I'm run the container as a non-root user.

When I run this I'm getting a permission denied error when trying to log to `/var/log/log.txt`.

I set up the non-root user in my `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
RUN apk add doas
RUN adduser -D myuser && addgroup mygroup && addgroup myuser mygroup
RUN echo 'myuser:123' | chpasswd
RUN echo 'permit persist :wheel' > /etc/doas.d/doas.conf

USER myuser
```

If I exec into the running container, and cd into `/var/log`, if I execute `touch test.txt` I also get a permission denied error.

I've tried various things e.g. `echo 'permit :wheel as root' > /etc/doas.d/doas.conf`, but can't seem to get this working (aside from just running the container as the root user, but I want to use a non-root user).

Answer (score 1):

By default the /var/log/ has the following permissions defined

```
drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog
```

Read a bit more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109864/1689983).

**It is not really a good idea** to append the application logs inside the Linux logs folder which is used by the system.

But if you want to try the above you can login the container and execute `sudo su - syslog` and then you could execute `touch test.txt` inside `var/log/`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Out of interest where do you think the correct location would be for *application* logs? I've gone through the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS), and it seems like `/var/logs` is the only place mentioned... oh and I can exec into the container as root and write files to `/var/log`, but the container runs as a non-root.

Comment: When running an application, one tends to write into `/var/log/application_name`, and, so, a root user will give you write access in that folder, not in `/var/log` right away: [_Most logs must be written to this directory **or an appropriate subdirectory**_](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s10.html).
Which is something you can definitely do in your _Dockerfile_ (`mkdir ... && chown ...`).